# Python, create a loop 'For'

Tags: python

With this query i will select so many row in this table `x_giolam`. 
-I want create a 'For' to which sum all 'giolam' with all rows i were select in this query.

```
cr.execute("""select name,giolam from x_giolam where name=%s"""%(ma_luong)),
```

i want to create a loop to sum all 'giolam' with rows were select

Comment: This really isn't so safe, in fact it's downright dangerous and susceptible to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Please consider calling execute like: `execute("""select name, giolam from x_giolam where name = ?""", ma_luong)`.

Comment: my teacher ive me a example :
def _get_maphieutien(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):
                res={}
                for obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
                        cr.execute(""" Select count (id) from x_phieutien""")
                        stt=cr.fetchone()[0]
                        res[obj.id] = stt
                return res'

Comment: i do it same a menthod for erp

Answer (score 5):

You should do that in the query, not in a for loop:

```
SELECT name, SUM(giolam) as giolam_sum FROM x_giolam WHERE name=%s GROUP BY name
```

Or, since you're limiting by `name=%s` already you don't need the `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT SUM(giolam) as giolam_sum FROM x_giolam WHERE name=%s
```

Comment: because i do it for erp and i have a atribute 'total' iwant create a loop and return a value

Answer (score 0):

As Michael noted, you should calculate the sum in the query.  If you are dead set on looping through each matching row you can do something like this::

```
cursor.execute("""select name,giolam from x_giolam where name=%s"""%(ma_luong)),
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print sum = sum + row.giolam
```

Adapted from [pyodbc refence](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor)